# Duplicate html tag with VIM

Tags: vim, ideavim

In [this](https://youtu.be/eDTi7lYR1VU?t=1837) video Erik Rasmussen edit his code from like this:

```
<div>
  <span>foo</span>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div>
  <span>foo</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>foo</span>
</div>
```

How is it posible? All I know is `vatyP` but it not produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried 3yyP. It seemed to work for me.